# What does the blue 0 mean in the top right hand corner of my camera?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera

I have a Samsung Galaxy s II and recently a 0 in a white box has appeared in my camera on the right hand corner. Why is this? What does it mean? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I don't suppose you could get us a photo of it?

Answer (score 3):

The [user manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201106/20110620164930378/GT-I9100_UM_EU_Eng_Rev.1.4_110615_Screen.pdf) (p.58) only shows one possible display of a number, which would be the number of photos you can take given the available space (No. 4 in the below screen example). It is in the top right, below the button to switch between front and back facing cameras. Zero would imply that you cannot take any more photos.

[image: Galaxy camera screen]

If you still have this problem, please try get someone else to take a photos of the screen as suggested if you don't have another phone or camera.