# number in the top right corner of the camera app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the blue 0 mean in the top right hand corner of my camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/what-does-the-blue-0-mean-in-the-top-right-hand-corner-of-my-camera)

What is the number shown in the top right corner of the camera app that comes installed with Android 2.3.5? It shows 905 right now but I don't know what it means. Does it have anything to do with the zoom or the light level or the space in the SD card for more pictures to be taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This number represents the approximate amount of pictures left you'll be able to take, according to the free space on the media portion of the phone (e.g. SD Card) and the currently chosen settings, such as resolution.

Comment: An artifact from the days when you had to worry about the amount of film you had left in your camera.

Comment: You'd be surprised how much this artifact helps on SD Card-less devices like Galaxy Nexus.